# Athena Workgroup usage alerts using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-athena

Is there any way to create Athena workgroup usage alert using terraform. I see in terraform resource block that there is no option to set using usage alert with SNS topic

I have tried terraform documentation and other online resources but never found any useful information

```
    resource "aws_athena_workgroup" "athena_team_workgroup" {
      for_each      = var.athena_workgroups
      name          = format("%s", each.key)
      description   = "Athena workgroup"
      force_destroy = false
      tags = merge({
        Name : format("%s-workgroup", each.key)
        UseCase : format("%s-data-sharing", each.key)
        UsedBy : format("%s", each.key)
        Description : "workgroup of Athena allows to query glue catalog databases and tables"
      }, local.tags)
    
      state = each.value
    
      configuration {
        enforce_workgroup_configuration    = true
        publish_cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
        bytes_scanned_cutoff_per_query     = 52428800000
        requester_pays_enabled             = false
        result_configuration {
          output_location = format("s3://%s/workgroups/%s/", module.s3_abi_athena_workgroups.bucket_name, each.key)
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Is there some code?

Comment: @MarkoE this resource block does not have option for configuration, i am using this terraform block for it, https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/athena_workgroup#publish_cloudwatch_metrics_enabled

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: You are sending the metrics already to CloudWatch. I think you can use CloudWatch to send notifications about usage based on relevant metrics.

Comment: Do you have any reference to do it ? @MarkoE

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

Answer (score 0):

Terraform doesn't seem to have a **workgroup-wide data usage control limit** feature (as documented on AWS Athena [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/workgroups-setting-control-limits-cloudwatch.html#configure-control-limit-per-workgroup)) available.

Nevertheless, it is possible to recreate the same functionality using terraform templates. In order to do that you'll need the following key components using lambda and/or SNS:

- setup a Cloudwatch alarm
- setup a Cloudwatch alarm rule

  - permissions to invoke lambda / or put permissions to write on SNS
- setup read outs and/or actuators

  - setup a Lambda function that will disable/enable a workgroup based on rule state (and optionally cancel all running queries)

    - permissions to list workgroups (`athena:ListWorkGroups`) and update them (`athena:UpdateWorkGroup`)
  - setup an SNS to fan-out messages and/or send alert

Please note that there is a lag between Athena WorkGroup metric release and triggering a Lambda function and consequently, all queries launched within that period will be charged for the amount of data being scanned.

Here is gist (not fully functional and not including the permissions section) how your terraform should look like if you're trying to disable the Athena Workgroup using an AWS lambda function. This example was put together after having a look at the way **workgroup-wide data usage control limit** is done via the dashboard:

```tf
variable "total_datascan_threshold" {
  description = "total amount of data scanned in bytes"
  type        = number
}

variable "period" {
  description = "period in seconds over which the specified statistic is applied"
  type        = number
}

resource "aws_athena_workgroup" "a_workgroup" {
      name          = "athena-wg"
      description   = "an Athena workgroup"
      force_destroy = false
      configuration {
        enforce_workgroup_configuration    = true
        publish_cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
        bytes_scanned_cutoff_per_query     = 52428800000
        requester_pays_enabled             = false
        result_configuration {
          output_location = "s3://results_bucket/queries/"
        }
      }
}

# athena workgroup alarm
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "athena_wg_datascan" {
  alarm_name          = "athena-wg-datascan"
  alarm_description   = "Monitors Athena WorkGroup total data scan"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  threshold           = format("%d", floor(var.total_datascan_treshold))
  treat_missing_data = "notBreaching"
  metric_query {
    id          = "wg1"
    return_data = "true"
    metric {
      metric_name = "ProcessedBytes"
      namespace   = "AWS/Athena"
      period      = format("%d", floor(var.period))
      stat        = "Sum"
      dimensions = {
        WorkGroup = "${aws_athena_workgroup.a_workgroup.id}"
      }
    }
  }
}

# event rule to switch athena workgroup
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "switch_athena_wg" {
  name        = "switch-athena-wg-state"
  description = "Switch Athena WorkGroup based on event rule"
  event_pattern = jsonencode(
    {
      "source" : [
        "aws.cloudwatch"
      ],
      "detail-type" : [
        "CloudWatch Alarm State Change"
      ],
      "resources" : [
        "${aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.athena_wg_datascan.arn}"
      ]
    }
  )
}

# connect eventbridge to lambda function
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "switch_athena_wg" {
  target_id = "switch-athena-wg"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.athena_wg_switch.arn
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.switch_athena_wg.name
}

# master switch lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_function" "athena_wg_switch" {
  function_name = "athena-wg-switch"
  filename      = "${path.module}/athena_wg_switch.zip"
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  handler = "main.lambda_handler"
  runtime = var.runtime
}

data "archive_file" "athena_wg_switch" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/athena-wg-switch/"
  output_path = "${path.module}/athena_wg_switch.zip"
}

# grant permissions to invoke lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "eventbridge_trigger" {
  statement_id  = "allow-eventbridge-trigger"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.athena_wg_switch.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.switch_athena_wg.arn
}
```

Lambda function code in `athena-wg-switch/main.py`:

```python
import os
from boto3 import client



class UnknownState(Exception):
        """Unable to handle workgroup state different than ENABLED or DISABLED"""

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        """
        Updates the Athena WorkGroup state bases on the alarm state value
        """
        athena = client("athena")

        response = None
        workgroup = [
                m["metricStat"]["metric"]["dimensions"]["WorkGroup"]
                for m in event["detail"]["configuration"]["metrics"]
                ][0]

        state = event["detail"]["state"]["value"]

        if state == "ALARM":
                new_state = "DISABLED"
        elif state == "OK":
                new_state = "ENABLED"
        else:
                raise UnknownState(f'Unexpected {event["detail"]} state: {event}')

        return athena.update_work_group(WorkGroup=workgroup, State=new_state)
```